# Calling a file locally

Tags: javascript

Please have a look at the entire code below and the line that I have pasted separately below
import * as THREE from 'https://unpkg.com/three/build/three.module.js';

I have downloaded three.module.js and would like to change the line of code to call this file from a local drive.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My first three.js app</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="module">
            import * as THREE from 'https://unpkg.com/three/build/three.module.js';

            const scene = new THREE.Scene();
            const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

            const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
            const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x0000FF } );
            const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            scene.add( cube );

            camera.position.z = 5;

            function animate() {
                requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
                cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

                renderer.render( scene, camera );
            }

            animate();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried several things but without success.

Comment: You aren't calling anything from HTML.You are doing so using JavaScript and you should remove the HTML tag and re-tag this as javascript. Also, remove the local tag as it has no useful meaning

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that You need to set up a local web server and load your page from this one. Then have the file "uploaded" that is copied into the path where the file/app will be hosted. Usually, the local server will be reached by typing http://localhost and depending on which port is running and which path you set your HTML file or app then You can use in your code a relative path to load the desired file.

There are tons of local web servers, just google it and get one for your OS.